# How to store really large string/character array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, .net-3.5

I'm trying to store a very large string which I will ultimately convert to a character array to carry out operations on the individual characters.The string can be up to 1 million characters long. I'd used a normal string to carry out my work so far but it won't work for such large strings.What inbuilt class can I use for this?

Comment: "it won't work for such large strings" - in what way? You can certainly create a string with a million characters in .NET.

Comment: if you are really worried use files and read and write to it in chunks?

Comment: @Osama, 2MB of memory is hardly a reason to resort to files...

Comment: :O Well,I submitted some code to a website, and it claimed the code was giving the wrong output, so I assumed that the problem must be with the large input!

Comment: can you add some code examples

Comment: @zmbq I completely agree. However the question asked for a "Class" that he could use so I suggested one :)

Comment: hm how about char[], List<char> or StringBuilder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you think you can't have such large strings. Anyway, you probably want to store that data in a string before converting it to a character array because you want to modify it.

If all you want to do is append data to it, you could use a `StringBuilder` for efficiently building your string, then convert it to a character array.

Comment: This especially a good idea if you're using .NET 4, since the StringBuilder implementation was changed from earlier versions.  The new approach uses a linked list of smaller character arrays rather than a potentially-huge contiguous block of memory.